# Swift - How to reload ViewController from a ModalPopupController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

i have 2 ViewControllers, one is named FirstViewController and it contains a UIImage and a UIButton, the second is named ModalPopupViewController and it contains 2 buttons

So on my FirstViewController when i push the UIButton it makes a "Cross Dissolve" transition over current context
On the ModalPopupViewController, when i push the first button, i choose a picture with UIImagePickerController and i save it, when i push the second button i dismiss the view but my picture appear only when i restart my app.
 How can i reload my FirstViewController when i leave the ModalPopupViewController ?

i tried to call `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear` but nothing append when i came back to FirstViewController from ModalPopupViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use delegate pattern

```
protocol ReloadManager {

    func reloadImageV(image:UIImage)
}
```

when you prsent the modal

```
let modal = ///

modal.delegate = self

present(modal//////

class FirstVC:UIViewController , ReloadManager {


    func reloadImageV(image:UIImage) {
      // reload here
    }
}


class ModalVC:UIViewController {

    var delegate:ReloadManager?


    @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender:UIButton) {

        delegate?.reloadImageV(image: sendedImage)

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

//

Remove the segue and inside the btn action that navigates to the modal do this , give the modal a storyboard identifer , cast it to the real modal class name

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "modalID") as! ModViewController

vc.delegate = self

vc.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true;

vc.definesPresentationContext = true;

vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: i think i have done something wrong, inside my `FirstViewController.swift` i have add outside of the class the protocol, then inside the class i have add the func and the SuperClass. Inside my `ModalPopupViewController` i have add the variable and the function inside my button action.

Comment: But i havn't these line inside my swift files `let modal = ///

modal.delegate = self

present(modal//////`

Comment: How do you present the modal ,, segue , present ?

Comment: i have used Interface Builder to make a "Present Modally" transition

Comment: where do you do self.performSegue

Comment: i don't use it, to pass data i save it with UserDefault